# suspend doesn't work on Dell Inspiron 1525

Tags: suspend

I'm having a Dell Inspiron 1525. Suspend and resume were working correctly.

All of a sudden, when I click the `suspend` menu option the system doesn't get suspended. Instead, it is being locked. Viewing `dmesg` output reveals

```
[48214.876143] sky2 eth0: disabling interface
[48215.844400] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[48215.872063] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
[48215.872070] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.00 seconds) done.
[48215.873464] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.00 seconds) done.
[48215.873582] PM: Entering mem sleep
[48215.873597] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[48225.872091] usbhid 6-2:1.0: suspend error -5
[48225.872100] pm_op(): usb_dev_suspend+0x0/0x20 returns -5
[48225.872104] PM: Device 6-2 failed to suspend: error -5
[48225.872106] PM: Some devices failed to suspend
[48225.876917] PM: resume of devices complete after 4.807 msecs
[48226.076192] PM: resume devices took 0.204 seconds
[48226.076203] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[48226.076205] Restarting tasks ... done.
[48226.388912] sky2 eth0: enabling interface
[48226.390582] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[48227.894532] sky2 eth0: Link is up at 100 Mbps, full duplex, flow control rx
[48227.894999] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[48237.172073] eth1: no IPv6 routers present
```

In particular `usbhid 6-2:1.0: suspend error -5`. Google didn't find anything useful about that.

How can I further troubleshoot this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

PM: Device 6-2 failed to suspend: error -5

suggests that there is a problem with suspending with that device. You can find out what is on Bus 6.2 by doing lsusb and looking at that.
If the problem persists, file a bug report with "ubuntu-bug linux"

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be clues earlier in the `dmesg` output.

Do

```
dmesg -T|grep Freez -A4
```

to look for particular processes that stops suspend from suspending, does it give anything?

In that case, see my answer here: [How to make "suspend" option to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2455/how-to-make-suspend-option-to-work/263498#263498) on how to automatically kill them before suspend.