# Suspend option is not working in Ubuntu 14.04 on Lenovo Z570

Tags: 14.04, suspend, laptop, lenovo

I'm new in the world of Linux and using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS version.

My question is how to make the 'Suspend' option work?

Whenever I click that option from my laptop, the screen becomes black at first, then my login screen comes after 2-3 seconds.

Nothing happens after that.

Comment: It's Laptop or Desktop ? @baila

Comment: i am using laptop. Model is Lenovo Z570. @Sridhar

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make "suspend" option to work?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2455/how-to-make-suspend-option-to-work)

Answer (score 1):

Open your command line (terminal) and enter this command to edit the config file:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

Copy and paste below lines into the file and save it.

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

After reboot it will work. (I too have same bug but in my case for hibernate too)

Comment: That does not work for me. @Ravan

Comment: @baila Does the first command not worked? or the final result

Comment: That did not work for me. I have followed whatever you suggested above.

Comment: Just I changed the first command,now please try again the whole step @baila

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly happening. I made some changes as per [this Ubuntu Forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1978290).

Then I checked the suspend log, which shows:

```
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd: 21: /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd: cannot create /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/unbind: Directory nonexistent
/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd: 21: /etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd: cannot create /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/unbind: Directory nonexistent
/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd suspend suspend: Returned exit code 2.
Thu Aug 20 19:59:44 IST 2015: Inhibit found, will not perform suspend
Thu Aug 20 19:59:44 IST 2015: Running hooks for resume
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend: success.
```

I then just deleted `/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd`. Now it works perfectly.

Someone please explain the reason for this behaviour.