# Ubuntu 14.04 - Suspend only locks screen

Tags: 14.04, suspend, power-management, overheating

I decided to install Ubuntu 14.04 onto my laptop (Asus G551JM). I wanted my laptop to suspend (sleep) when it was not being used for a specific period of time and whenever I close the lid. After today's class, I arrived at home and realized my laptop was overheating to the max because it wasn't on suspend enclosed in my bag.

I tried various solutions such as removing `#` from `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` but then I realized suspending was only locking my screen. Even when I use the suspend button from the top right, it still only locks the screen. Even using `sudo pm-suspend`, it has the same result...

Comment: refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/663733/suspend-option-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04/663782#663782)

Comment: Ok @Long Le then I will make it as answer!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suspend option is not working in Ubuntu 14.04 on Lenovo Z570](https://askubuntu.com/questions/663733/suspend-option-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04-on-lenovo-z570)

Comment: @Zanna .. you are right. It was the link that Ravan referred to at Sep 11 '15 at 2:32 above ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your command line (terminal) and enter this command to edit the config file:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

Copy and paste below lines into the file and save it.

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

After reboot it will work. (I too have same bug but in my case for hibernate too)